# Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Tags: jquery

it was working at my computer but when i try to put it in host .. it get this error
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/common.js"></script>
```

---

```
if($.browser.mozilla||$.browser.opera ){document.removeEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",$.ready,false);document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){$.ready()},false)}
jQuery.event.remove( window, "load", jQuery.ready );
jQuery.event.add( window, "load", function(){ jQuery.ready(); } );
```

any help ?

Comment: It looks odd to use `$` *and* `jQuery` .. and it looks odd to do whatever hack that is supposed to do. Is it required in an appropriately recent jQuery version? Normally, `jQuery(function ($) { .. })` is sufficient ..

Comment: BTW $.browser has been removed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load the jQuery library before your `script`:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Here ya go: `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` -- in case there are any doubts about loading the script on the serv

Comment: thx @tymeJV, i could edit my post, i'm just too lazy

Comment: @George Cummins thx but OP is using $.browser which has been removed